# Concatenate a MVC Razor Model Object Name for use in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am looking over another developers code and can't help but think there has to be a better way to clean-up the code. I have been searching and trying different ways for the past day and a half. Any help would be appreciated.

We have a MVC4 Razor website that we are working on for Executive Dashboards. The website is working, but performance is not where it needs to be. I have started to do a code review and found that the business logic code is all in the view.

I know the logic should mainly be in the model and controller, but he has but everything in the view. Due to the complexity of this project and the amount of data we have to pull, I want to start cleaning it up by rewriting in baby steps if possible.

The first thing I want to tackle is creating a routine to handle the code below so that hundreds of lines of code can be reduced to a smaller number. I plan on setting the branch number based upon the selected value of a dropdown list on the page.

Currently he is declaring the following:

```
var b1 = Model.Branches.Where(b => b.BranchID.Equals(1)).First();
var b2 = Model.Branches.Where(b => b.BranchID.Equals(2)).First();
var b3 = Model.Branches.Where(b => b.BranchID.Equals(3)).First();
...
var branch = $("#BranchList").val();
```

and using those variables in a switch (below):

```
switch (branch){
                case "City":
                    if (@(b1.YTDSales) > 0) { 
                        data1.setCell(0, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("ADMIN")).First().YTDSales1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("ADMIN")).First().YTDSales1, 0))));
                        data1.setCell(1, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("BUS")).First().YTDSales1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("BUS")).First().YTDSales1, 0))));
                        data1.setCell(2, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("F&I")).First().YTDSales1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("F&I")).First().YTDSales1, 0))));
                        data1.setCell(3, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("NEW")).First().YTDSales1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("NEW")).First().YTDSales1, 0))));
                        data1.setCell(4, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("PARTS")).First().YTDSales1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("PARTS")).First().YTDSales1, 0))));
                        data1.setCell(5, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("SERVICE")).First().YTDSales1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("SERVICE")).First().YTDSales1, 0))));
                        data1.setCell(6, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("USED")).First().YTDSales1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("USED")).First().YTDSales1, 0))));
                    } else { 
                        draw1 = false; 
                    }
                    if (@(b1.YTDGP) > 0) { 
                        data2.setCell(0, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("ADMIN")).First().YTDGP1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("ADMIN")).First().YTDGP1, 0))));
                        data2.setCell(1, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("BUS")).First().YTDGP1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("BUS")).First().YTDGP1, 0))));
                        data2.setCell(2, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("F&I")).First().YTDGP1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("F&I")).First().YTDGP1, 0))));
                        data2.setCell(3, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("NEW")).First().YTDGP1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("NEW")).First().YTDGP1, 0))));
                        data2.setCell(4, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("PARTS")).First().YTDGP1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("PARTS")).First().YTDGP1, 0))));
                        data2.setCell(5, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("SERVICE")).First().YTDGP1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("SERVICE")).First().YTDGP1, 0))));
                        data2.setCell(6, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("USED")).First().YTDGP1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("USED")).First().YTDGP1, 0))));
                    } else {
                        draw2 = false; 
                    }
                    if (@(b1.YTDNetProfit) > 0) { 
                        data3.setCell(0, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("ADMIN")).First().YTDNetProfit1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("ADMIN")).First().YTDNetProfit1, 0))));
                        data3.setCell(1, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("BUS")).First().YTDNetProfit1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("BUS")).First().YTDNetProfit1, 0))));
                        data3.setCell(2, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("F&I")).First().YTDNetProfit1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("F&I")).First().YTDNetProfit1, 0))));
                        data3.setCell(3, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("NEW")).First().YTDNetProfit1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("NEW")).First().YTDNetProfit1, 0))));
                        data3.setCell(4, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("PARTS")).First().YTDNetProfit1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("PARTS")).First().YTDNetProfit1, 0))));
                        data3.setCell(5, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("SERVICE")).First().YTDNetProfit1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("SERVICE")).First().YTDNetProfit1, 0))));
                        data3.setCell(6, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("USED")).First().YTDNetProfit1 < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("USED")).First().YTDNetProfit1, 0))));
                    } else {
                        draw3 = false; 
                    }
                    data4.addRows(1);
                    data4.setCell(0, 0, '@(b1.BranchCode)');
                    data4.setCell(0, 1, @(Math.Round(b1.YTDSales, 0)));
                    data5.addRows(1);
                    data5.setCell(0, 0, '@(b1.BranchCode)');
                    data5.setCell(0, 1, @(Math.Round(b1.YTDTotalExp * -1, 0)));
                    break;
...
```

City in the case statement could be Atlanta, Dallas, Nashville, etc.

I want to turn all of this into a routine that removes all the duplicate lines. The following is pseudo-code to show what I'm thinking.

```
var BranchID = null;
switch (branch){
    case "Atlanta":
        BranchID = 1;
        BRModel = "b"+BranchID <-- This would be used below.
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

if (@(**BRModel**.YTDSales) > 0) { 
    data1.setCell(0, 1, @((Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("ADMIN")).First().YTDSales**[BranchID]** < 0 ? 0 : Math.Round(Model.DeptTotals.Where(d => d.Department.Equals("ADMIN")).First().YTDSales**[BranchID]**, 0))));
...
```

Part of the change I'm thinking about would be to change the dropdown list values to the actual BranchID instead of using the city name. That way I could remove the switch all together.

This would allow us to scale properly instead of hard-coding each branch location. Is this possible to do? Is it best practice or is there a better way?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: An advice to you is to take it all the view and put in the model, making the view only render the data, and oh yes you could do a good cleaning code

Comment: Yep, either way the code will undertake a lot of cleaning/rewrite.

Comment: To my mind, using "baby steps" in your case is wasting time. Because you instead off number of the small "bad" things, you are creating one big "bad" piece of code. It request sophisticated and complex solution for your "big piece" that aren't useful in refactored code and  difficult to support. Create new model (that duplicate your "bad" model), implement (copy from view if it is possible) new code and put in your new view. Take off all past code. It is case when create new is easy that refactor past "solution".

Comment: You need to start by outlining what the front end needs to *do* -- it's quite hard to tell with the C#/Js soup, but I'm imagining this can all be cooked down to a few lines of js and one or 2 lines of c# with linq, which should be moved to a mapping layer

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I totally agree that we are going to have to go back to the Model layer. I thought about this all last night and came to the same conclusion that it would be a waste of time to take baby steps. I'm in my office today reworking the Model.

Comment: How do I give you each a +1 for the help?

Comment: @DPhillips You don't have enough reputation for this. Don't care, this site is for helping people, but doesn't getting more score :).